# Help constructing the informal F.O.L. interpretation of: "If $f(x)=x^n$ for some natural number $n$, then $f'(a)=na^{n-1}$"

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Here is a theorem that I proved using induction:

> If $f(x)=x^n$ for some natural number $n$, then $f'(a)=na^{n-1}$.

Using pseudo FOL (which helps me orient my proofs...**emphasis** on pseudo), I wrote this as:

$$\forall n \in \mathbb N \left[ f_n(x)=x^n \rightarrow \forall a \in \mathbb R \left[f_{n}'(a)=na^{n-1} \right] \right]$$

For my induction proof, my antecedent accordingly switched across the three classic inductive values:

1. $f_1(x)=x^1$ (base case)
2. $f_n(x)=x^n$ (assumption)
3. $f_{n+1}(x)=x^{n+1}$ (inductive step)

Obviously, $f_1 \neq f_n \neq f_{n+1}$. This had me wondering if the internal conditional that is being universally quantified over is actually an existential claim. Using pseudo FOL once more, **am I proving the following claim**:

$$\forall n \in \mathbb N \left [ \exists f \left(f(x)=x^n \rightarrow \forall a \in \mathbb R \left[f'(a)=na^{n-1} \right] \right) \right]$$

This seemed a little odd to me because I do not frequently see existential quantifiers with conditional statements. Moreover, the function that we want to prove exists is literally already generated by assuming the antecedent.

Any input on the correct interpretation (informal as it may be) would be appreciated.

Comment: Actually it should be a universal quantifier: "for every $n$, it is the case that whenever $f$ is the function $f(x)=x^n$ we have [stuff]," which in turn translates to (something like) $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}[\forall f([\forall x(f(x)=x^n)]\implies [stuff])].$$ Think about translating "The Eiffel tower is in Paris" as "Every object with the 'is-the-Eiffel-tower' property is in Paris." An existential quantifier won't behave how you want here.

Comment: I have never done FOL so obviously can't answer, but I'd think nonexistence wouldn't be a problem since  in that case you'd have a vacuously true statement?

Comment: @NoahSchweber So even though there is only one unique function (e.g. $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ where $x \mapsto x^n$) that exists for a given $n$ and satisfies our criteria (much in the same way there is only one such building that satisfies the criteria of being the Eiffel tower), we still use the universal quantifier (in the book I'm working with, all functions are assumed to have the domain of $\mathbb R$ unless otherwise stated). Good to know, thank you.

Comment: @Alan yes, good catch.

Comment: @NoahSchweber should probably convert that to an answer?

Comment: @Alan the correct notion then is probably something like: $$\forall n \in \mathbb N [\forall f [f(x)=x^n \rightarrow [\text{stuff}_n] ] ] \rightarrow \forall n \in \mathbb N [\exists f [ \text{stuff}_n]]$$. ... Namely, the function with the mapping rule $f(x)=x^n$

Comment: Actually you can write what would be called a let-statement in CS as either an existential or a universal. If $\exists_1 f, P(f)$, then $\forall f(P(f) \to Q(f))$ and $\exists f(P(f) \land Q(f))$ are equivalent. In this example $P(f) \equiv \forall n(f(x) = x^n$, so we certainly have $\exists_1 f, P(f)$,.

Comment: @NoahSchweber OP wants a FOL statement, $f$ is a function symbol here, so in first order language shouldn't we avoid quantification over functions/relations in general? Can you elaborate such use here?

Comment: @mohottnad I'm a noob, so this may be incorrect, but my understanding was that in the context of ZFC, the symbol $f$ (which is denoting a function as defined in set theory) is a set. Therefore, it is reasonable to universally quantify over it. I think the issue that you described is specific to quantifying over *formulas*. $\forall f [\varphi(f)]$ is valid. $\forall \varphi [\varphi(f)]$ is invalid. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: In pure set theory such as ZFC the only objects are sets. If you retract $f$ to a set (of ordered pairs), then you can also retract formula (relation) to set via set building with [axiom schema of specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification). Also remember a total or partial function can always be turned into a formula. And then effectively you're using a many-sorted FOL adding any sorts you want. Seems based on your first $L$-sentence, you don't need the conditional antecedent at all after predefined function symbols $f_n$ & $f_n'$ added to your formal language.

Comment: @mohottnad hah, I think you know more than me, but my understanding of the axiom schema of specification was not that it allowed you to "set-ify" formulas, but that it allowed you "set-ify" elements in a pre-existing set that satisfy some formula. These seem distinctly different as it pertains to your comment. There is a difference between "$\varphi$" and "$x \in A \land \varphi(x)$". As far as I know, $\varphi$, in and of itself, is not a set.